# Access dialog of one project from dialog of another project in visual studio c++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, dialog

I created two separate executables projects using MFC and dialogs.

What I want to do -
Run one project and use its dialog to open another project dialog like on clicking a button in one dialog open another project dialog. I am here talking about another project and not the same project.

Just one executable to access two project dialogs and to call one dialog from another dialog.

Is it possible?? Or do I have to incorporate whole one project into another project??

I am new to visual studio so please suggest something. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do with the two EXE projects, instead you make one of your projects a DLL and call the DLL from EXE (the DLL will be loaded into the same process space as the EXE). There are a few different ways you can write the DLL, but this is a very big topic. Here's a good starting point on the Microsoft web site:

[Microsoft: DLLs in Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ez7dh12.aspx)

Comment: thanks but I was able to use them for my project independently.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the mechanism that snowdude has suggested.  However, if you need to create multiple executable files (ie. .exe), you can use the [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to gain access to the dialog code in the other executable.  LoadLibrary can't be used to run the other executable, but, you can use the [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx) function to provide the address to a function within the other executable that will run the dialog code.